# Firebase: Retrieve information from nested Childs (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, swift3

I have the following Json structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "yebl4egdQAcKyO7fRx3" : {
      "Calls" : {
        "Call_1" : {
          "CallNumber" : "1",
          "CallStatus" : "activ",
          "CallTitle" : "Test",
          "username" : "Kurt"
        },
        "Call_2" : {
          "CallNumber" : "2",
          "CallStatus" : "activ",
          "CallTitle" : "kfkf",
          "username" : "Kurt"
        },
      },
      "Country" : "USA",
      "Date of Birth" : "19770101",
      "Gender" : "M",
      "email" : "kurt@küde.com",
      "username" : "Kurt"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I try to retrieve the following data:

1) the number of calls within the child "Calls". I tried to do this with this code:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").child("Calls").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            let CallCount = snapshot.childrenCount

            self.checkCall = Int(CallCount)

            print("check")
            print(self.checkCall)

        })
```

The code should give back the number of calls of every individual user. But this code returns zero. It seems that I do not correctly address my observation because my Json tree is nested.

2) I need to get back the whole dictionary of an individual call for all the users (assuming there is not just one like in the example):

```
    struct SingleCall {

        let callNumber: String!
        let callStatus: String!
        let callTitle : String!
        let username : String!
            }

 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").child("Calls").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            var newItems: [SingleCall] = []
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                if self.Filter == (rest.value as? NSDictionary)!["Category"] as! String {

                    let callNumber        = (rest.value as? NSDictionary)!["CallNumber"] as! String

                    let callStatus        = (rest.value as? NSDictionary)!["CallStatus"] as! String

                    let callTitle        = (rest.value as? NSDictionary)!["CallTitle"] as! String

                    let username        = (rest.value as? NSDictionary)!["username"] as! String

                    newItems.append(SingleCall(callNumber: callNumber, callStatus: callStatus, callTitle: callTitle, username : username))

                }
            }
        })
```

This does not work as well, because it seems that I do not address the Childs correctly to retrieve the information. I also checked several entries here but couldn't help myself with the entries. I am programming in Swift 3 and would appreciate solutions in that language though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your main problem causing you not to get any calls is that you have missed a child path on this line `databaseRef.child("users").child("Calls")` which is the user uid. I've tested this with Firebase using the JSON above and it works.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var users = Array<User>()

    var filtered = Array<User>()

    var filter = "active"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>> else { return }

            for (uid, value) in data {

                if let user = User(uid: uid, dict: value) {

                    self.users.append(user)

                } else {

                    print("Incomplete User Data.")
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func filterCalls(){

        self.filtered.removeAll()

        for user in users {

            let calls = user.calls.filter { $0.status == self.filter }

            var newUser = user

            newUser.calls = calls

            self.filtered.append(newUser)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return self.users[section].username
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return self.users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if users.count > section {

            return self.users[section].calls.count
        }

        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.users[indexPath.section].calls[indexPath.row].title

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.users[indexPath.section].calls[indexPath.row].number

        return cell
    }
}

struct User {

    var uid: String

    var country: String

    var dob: String

    var gender: String

    var email: String

    var username: String

    var calls: Array<Call>

    init?(uid: String, dict: Dictionary<String,Any>) {

        guard

            let country = dict["Country"] as? String,

            let dob = dict["Date of Birth"] as? String,

            let gender = dict["Gender"] as? String,

            let email = dict["email"] as? String,

            let username = dict["username"] as? String,

            let calls = dict["Calls"] as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>

        else {

            return nil
        }

        self.uid = uid

        self.country = country

        self.dob = dob

        self.gender = gender

        self.email = email

        self.username = username

        self.calls = Array<Call>()

        for (_, value) in calls {

            guard let call = Call(dict: value) else { continue }

            self.calls.append(call)
        }

        self.calls.sort { $0.number < $1.number }

        self.calls = self.calls.filter { $0.status == "active" } // This will filter the array so only the active calls are there.
    }
}

struct Call {

    var number: String

    var status: String

    var title: String

    var username: String

    init?(dict: Dictionary<String,String>) {

        guard

            let number = dict["CallNumber"],

            let status = dict["CallStatus"],

            let title = dict["CallTitle"],

            let username = dict["username"]

        else {

            return nil
        }

        self.number = number

        self.status = status

        self.title = title

        self.username = username
    }
}
```

This will make the table view look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Tristan. Sorry, but I struggle now a little bit in making the information in the Call available for a TableView. Would you have a piece of advice for me in respect to this as well? thanks

Comment: One last question: If I know would like to filter for only calls with status active, how do I do this? I understand the concept you proposed but I still struggle in handling it practically. You help is much appreciated

Comment: You can use something like this to filter an array `calls.filter { $0.status == "active" }`. I have added this to the code above in the User init method.

Comment: Thanks, got it. What if the filter comes from a Var (string) in ViewDidLoad (e.g. when you have different categories that change this Var). If I try to set the filter equal to this Var it returns an error: instance member cannot be used

Comment: I have added a filter function above. I don't really understand how you want it, but this might give you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Genius, now I slowly getting it. Many many helps, you have been a true help

Comment: Additional question: If I now would like to add to the Struct Call a priceHistory in the form of a Dictionary, how do I have to do this?

Comment: Can you add a sample of this dictionary to your question? @DU.DE

Comment: for i in 1 ..< 251  {
      ref.child("users").child(self.userID!).child("Calls").child("Call_"+self.CallNum!).child("priceHist").updateChildValues([String(i):1])
        } Essentially its just instead of a  String like the "title" a dictionary with a sequence of numbers...

Comment: Does it need to be a `Dictionary<String,Int>`? Becuase if you are just storing a bunch of numbers, you might be better off using an `Array<Int>`.

Comment: If you can explain what kind of data you expect the price history to have then I'll be able to give you an answer.

Comment: You are right, actually an array could work as well. How would it look for an array? In the tableview I than should be able to see the last price.

Comment: to add to this: the price history should be first of all just a series of numbers. another function will override these figures over time.

Comment: Tristan, would it be possible with this kind of Array?

Comment: I'm still quite confused about how you want this. I think you just need to add another variable to the struct, and then in the guard statement add something like this: `let priceHistory = dict["priceHistory"] as? Array<Int>`